# iOS and Airprint - printed PDF chopped off

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, airprint

We have written an app that generates a PDF.

Which can be:

- Opened with `UIDocumentInteractionController`
- Emailed with `MFMailComposeViewController`
- Or printed with `UIPrintInteractionController`

The first two are working fine, but when printed, the edges of my PDF are chopped off.

What is the optimal size each page should be?  We followed the size on [this example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html), 612x792.

If sent to iBooks or emailed, the PDF looks just fine.  The bottom is just chopped off when printed.

Comment: 612x792 == 8.5x11 inches. Could your printer (or iOS regional settings) be setting differently ? e.g. ISO A4

Comment: Almost all printers can't actually print all the way to the edge of the page (they once told me this at Kinko's), so the chopped off part is probably where this is happening.  I would think other people would have this issue as well, though. Maybe I need to allow 1/4 inch around all sides?

Comment: Photo printer are generally borderless. Weird that you only lose bottom and not the right (or left) part (as they can't generally can't print up to the right/left borders either).

Comment: I think that is just how my layout is setup -- more layout is on the bottom edge.  This isn't a photo printer either, but a Dell Laserjet that supports Airprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 612x774 (1/4 inch smaller height) as the page size.  This seemed to print just fine on both regular printers and photo printers.

Comment: Is there a way to print if printer is not Airprint compatible ?

Comment: Only way is to use 3rd party software running on a desktop computer. Such as this one: http://www.collobos.com/airprint We bought a $80 dell printer for development, which was worth it.